As per Datasheet of BC817-40 the typical hfe value is 400 but in ltspice simulation for 143 volts the hfe value we are getting is 122 why?

We are using this circuit for the input load circuit. This circuit will work for the input voltage range from 24 to 143 V input voltage. For 24 V typical value (25 degree) collector current from the PZTA42 transistor is 10 mA as per LTspice simulation and for 143 V input we observed that the hfe of the BC817-40 transistor according the datasheet for typical value is 400 but in the simulation we observed that for 143 V typical value for the BC817-40 transistor's hfe in simulation is 122. Means the hfe according to datasheet is 400
but in LTspice simulation we are getting hfe as 122 for 143 typical value but for 110 V we are getting hfe as 403 in simulation so why there is difference in LTspice simulation hfe values for 110 volts and 143 V. Because in worst case calculations we are using hfe as 400 for all the voltages so the there is difference in the simulation results and calculation results.

The max rated voltage is 45, so what the model does at 143 V is probably not intended.

What is Vce under the conditions you mention? If it is too low, hFE will, of course, be less.

T2 base is 1.42 volts, so T2 emitter is ~0.72 volts.  T2 collector is .853 volts so Vce is ~0.15 volts.

What you see is perfectly normal.
Just like the data sheet says, the hfe is "typically" 400.
It will not be 400.
It will have a huge range of 250 to 600, as per multiple BC817-40 datasheets from different manufacturers.
And even that range is achieved under specific measurement conditions. For example multiple manufacturers state that under conditions of 1.0V Vce and 100mA Ic, the hfe range is 250 to 600.

Can you give me the solution to calculate the total current flowing from the transistor t1 pzta41

@Shreyas19 No, your question wasn't about it. But I will give you a hint; in general, any circuit you design must not depend on any specific hfe value. They are not good designs. A good design will not depend on any specific hfe value, it's just that the transistor you will buy will have enough hfe for the job.

The NXP BC817-40  model I have in my LTspice installation has an hFE of 333 at Vce=1V and Ic = 100mA. It's about 380 at Vce=1V and Ic = 10mA.
The BF parameter in the model is a bit over 400.
Since your Vce is so low  (150mV rather than 1V) the transistor is almost saturated and the hFE will tend to be significantly lower, depending on the collector current. At low current it should still be pretty high (>300).
Here is the model I have:
.model BC817-40 NPN(IS=6.286E-14 NF=0.9917 ISE=4.53E-15 NE=1.774 BF=416.3 IKF=0.4913 VAF=98.08 NR=0.9895 ISC=1.877E-13 NC=1.3 BR=24.49 IKR=0.203 VAR=25 RB=1 IRB=1000 RBM=1 RE=0.2256 RC=0.143 XTB=0 EG=1.11 XTI=3 CJE=3.568E-11 VJE=0.726 MJE=0.3721 TF=4.826E-10 XTF=120 VTF=3.654 ITF=5.104 PTF=0 CJC=1.296E-11 VJC=0.3241 MJC=0.3742 XCJC=0.455 TR=7E-11 CJS=0 VJS=0.75 MJS=0.333 FC=0.8662 Vceo=45 Icrating=500m mfg=NXP)

